# Gentoo ebuild USE label with a '*'

Tags: package-managers, gentoo

I use emerge to check the status of ebuild, and I get this:

```
gentoo ~ # emerge -pv libvirt

These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!
[ebuild   R    ] app-emulation/libvirt-0.9.10-r4  USE="libvirtd lxc nls policykit python udev -avahi* -caps -debug -iscsi -lvm -macvtap -nfs -numa -openvz -parted -pcap -phyp -qemu -sasl* (-selinux) -uml -virt-network* -virtualbox* -xen" 0 kB
```

The USE label avahi*, virt-network*, sasl*, virt-network* virtualbox* , what does the '*' mean in these labels. Thanks. I think these packages are already installed . Right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just look at man page: http://linuxreviews.org/man/emerge/ Everything is explain there.

'R' stands for: rebuild (specific version of package is installed already)

'*' stands for: change from/to enabled state' - If use flags changed, portage will prompt you to rebuild packages because the use flags might have a significant impact on package functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Compared to your currently installed libvirt, this new emerge will remove avahi module.

This might come from several possibilities :

- Change in make.conf USE
- Change in /etc/portage/package.use
- Change of profile
- Previously compiled libvirt with forced USE flags (i.e. USE="avahi" emerge libvirt)